# Ignoring implicit Array creation in the output JSON

Tags: jolt

So currently if the input is

```json
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "tuna": "marlin"
}
```

The spec is

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "foo": "baz",
      "tuna": "baz"
    }
  }
]
```

The output is

```json
{
  "baz" : [ "bar", "marlin" ]
}
```

How do I make jolt not to create an array, but instead override the values of the "baz" key with the last element of the array?

Expected output

```json
{
  "baz" : "marlin"
}
```

Comment: Excuse me but it's not clear what you yearn to ask. We already simply get the expected output by simply using `"tuna": "baz"`. What's the exact logic behind?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I am trying to not get an array of values that are assigned to same key, but instead replace one value with another.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you only want to get the last element of the array. So, add one more spec to yours of operation type **modify-overwrite-beta** along with **lastElement()** function such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "baz"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=lastElement(@(1,&))"
    }
  }
]
```

in which no need to explicitly write each key within the **shift** spec, rather replace them with an asterisk. Then, the asterisk within the second spec also represents all of the keys(in this case, this is only `baz`), and ampersand next to that copies the name of the key in order to represent the relative value.

Comment: Thanks, several operations in a row actually solve this issue